# How to change the return key of uitextfield to "Apply"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to change the text of return key of UITextField to "Apply".

Comment: You can't. See the docs for `UIReturnKeyType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are limited to the following possibilities for the return key: Return, Go, Google, Join, Next, Route, Search, Send, Yahoo, Done, and EmergencyCall

Use UIReturnKeyType or Interface Builder to set this